# WCF open a silverlight OOB

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-oob

I have a WCF solution with utilities in my software.
Now, I need open a silverlight OOB whem execute some operation in WCF.
Basically, i open OOB and pass a xml file to it.

PS: silverlight OOB and WCF are in separated solutions on visual studio.

How can I do this? Any example or suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that you can do this.

Your Silverlight OOB application can call a WCF service. But your WCF service cannot open a Silverlight application.

Comment: I searched for it and found the "SLLauncher.exe"
But I don't know if it can be used in this situation, it's complex

Comment: Interesting program. But this is used for a user to launch an OOB app from a menu. The problem is that a WCF service is on the server, the OOB is on the client. You may be able to get it to work, but you must first have a way to identify which client you want to run the OOB on, and then you would have to disable a lot of the security. I would not recommend this solution.